# How to iterate through Objects of Objects in firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, firebase

This is my firebase data structure below

[image]

I know how to iterate bymonth but how can i iterate through each individual month and then access something inside the id `-Kukj` etc. These ids are generated randomly so I need a way to be able to access them and then there contents inside. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

To iterate through the children of a node, [use `DataSnapshot.forEach()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#forEach). Since this itself returns another snapshot, you can use it to iterate structures arbitrarily deep.